# I have error "[object HTMLInputElement]" when use nested loop for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, nested

```js
            var i = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var length_rate = [];
            var format_value = [];
            var count_format = $("input[id='length']").length;

            for (i = 1; i <= count_format; i++) {

                    $("input[name='length__" + i + "']").on("change", function() {
                        var length = $("input[name='length__" + i + "']").val();

                        if (use_for.includes("Website") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/400;
                        } else if (use_for.includes("PR") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/800;
                        } else if (use_for.includes("Review") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/600;
                        } else {
                            var length_rate = 1;
                        };

                        $("#format").on("change", function(){

                            var format = [];

                            $.each($("input[name='format__" + i + "[]']:checked"), function(){
                                format.push($(this).val());
                            });
                                var format_select = format.join(", ");

                                if (format_select.includes("SEO") == true) {
                                    var format_value_seo = 0.5;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_seo = 0;
                                };

                                if (format_select.includes("PR") == true) {
                                    var format_value_pr = 1.5;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_pr = 0;
                                };

                                if (format_select.includes("Review") == true) {
                                    var format_value_review = 2;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_review = 0;
                                };

                            value[i] = (format_value_seo + format_value_pr + format_value_review)*length_rate;

                            return false;
                        });

                        $("#format").triggerHandler('change'); 
                    });

                    $("#length").triggerHandler('change');

                };

            // Set price

            var sum_value = value.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a + b;
            }, 0); 

            var price = sum_value;
```

```html
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f10713-p385-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
  <div class="screen-reader-response" role="alert" aria-live="polite"></div>
  <form action="/vi/viet-bai-content/#wpcf7-f10713-p385-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form init" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div style="display: none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="10713"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.2.2"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f10713-p385-o1"><input type="hidden"
        name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="385"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_posted_data_hash" value=""><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_hidden_group_fields" value="[&quot;custom&quot;]"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_hidden_groups" value="[&quot;notes&quot;]">
      <input
        type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_visible_groups" value="[]"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_repeaters" value="[]"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_steps" value="{}"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7cf_options" value="{&quot;form_id&quot;:10713,&quot;conditions&quot;:[{&quot;then_field&quot;:&quot;notes&quot;,&quot;and_rules&quot;:[{&quot;if_field&quot;:&quot;fresh&quot;,&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;equals&quot;,&quot;if_value&quot;:&quot;Custom&quot;}]}],&quot;settings&quot;:{&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;animation_intime&quot;:200,&quot;animation_outtime&quot;:200,&quot;conditions_ui&quot;:&quot;normal&quot;,&quot;notice_dismissed&quot;:false}}"></div>
    <p><label><b>Content sử dụng cho:</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap use_for"><select name="use_for" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="use_for" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Website">Website</option><option value="Facebook">Facebook</option><option value="Newspaper">Newspaper</option><option value="Email">Email</option></select></span></label>
    </p>
    <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap fresh"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="fresh"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="fresh[]" value="100% viết mới, không copy"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">100% viết mới, không copy</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="fresh[]" value="Image"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Image</span></label>
      </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="fresh[]" value="Custom"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Custom</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </p>
    <div data-wpcf7-group-id="content_details" id="content_details" tabindex="1" class="wpcf7-field-groups ">
      <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
        <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__1"><input type="text" name="subject__1" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
              <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__1"><input type="number" name="length__1" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__1"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__1[]" value="Ebook"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ebook</span></label>
          </span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove " style="display: none;">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__1"
            value="3"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
        <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__2"><input type="text" name="subject__2" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
              <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__2"><input type="number" name="length__2" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__2"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__2[]" value="Ebook"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ebook</span></label>
          </span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove ">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__2" value="3"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="wpcf7-field-group">
        <table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:70%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Tiêu đề bài viết</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject__3"><input type="text" name="subject__3" value="Tác giả tự đặt tiêu đề cho bài này" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
              <th style="width:30%;text-transform:none;border-bottom:none">
                <label><b>Độ dài content</b><br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap length__3"><input type="number" name="length__3" value="400" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number" id="length" aria-invalid="false"></span></label>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap format__3"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="format"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="SEO"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">SEO</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="PR"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">PR</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="Review"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Review</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="format__3[]" value="Ebook"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Ebook</span></label>
          </span>
          </span>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-remove ">-</button><button type="button" class="wpcf7-field-group-add ">+</button><input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-field-group-count" name="_wpcf7_groups_count[content_details]__3" value="3"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Nhấn + để thêm bài viết tiếp theo</p>
    <div data-id="notes" data-orig_data_id="notes" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="wpcf7cf-hidden"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap custom"><textarea name="custom" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Dàn ý yêu cầu, bài viết mẫu, ghi chú..."></textarea></span></div>
    <div class="total"><input type="submit" value="Gửi yêu cầu" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div id="left">
          <span class="label">Phí ước tính: </span><span class="form-input"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap price"><input type="text" name="price" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="price" readonly="" aria-invalid="false"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpcf7-response-output" role="alert" aria-hidden="true"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I use for to get array of value

I'm successful if run loop for only "#format" element. But it have error when I make nested loop with "input 'length' name" to get "price".

> Error: [object HTMLInputElement]

It seems problem with array in type of data

I run loop in array for 2 nested elements like this:

** It's ok if I have only element, not nested.

```
            var i = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var length_rate = [];
            var format_value = [];
            var count_format = $("input[id='length']").length;

            for (i = 1; i <= count_format; i++) {

                    $("input[name='length__" + i + "']").on("change", function() {
                        var length = $("input[name='length__" + i + "']").val();
            
                        if (use_for.includes("Website") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/400;
                        } else if (use_for.includes("PR") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/800;
                        } else if (use_for.includes("Review") == true) {
                            var length_rate = length/600;
                        } else {
                            var length_rate = 1;
                        };
            
                        $("#format").on("change", function(){

                            var format = [];
                
                            $.each($("input[name='format__" + i + "[]']:checked"), function(){
                                format.push($(this).val());
                            });
                                var format_select = format.join(", ");
        
                                if (format_select.includes("SEO") == true) {
                                    var format_value_seo = 0.5;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_seo = 0;
                                };
                    
                                if (format_select.includes("PR") == true) {
                                    var format_value_pr = 1.5;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_pr = 0;
                                };
                    
                                if (format_select.includes("Review") == true) {
                                    var format_value_review = 2;
                                } else {
                                    var format_value_review = 0;
                                };
                
                            value[i] = (format_value_seo + format_value_pr + format_value_review)*length_rate;
                
                            return false;
                        });
                
                        $("#format").triggerHandler('change'); 
                    });
            
                    $("#length").triggerHandler('change');
    
                };
        
            // Set price

            var sum_value = value.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a + b;
            }, 0); 
    
            var price = sum_value;
```

This is single loop I 've done. It's ok for .length and extract sum of single loop in "#format" array:

```
        $("#content_details").on("change", function(){
            
            var i = 0;
            var price = 0;
            var format_value = [];
            var count_format = $("input[id='length']").length;
            
            for (i = 1; i <= count_format; i++) {
                
                var format = [];
                
                $.each($("input[name='format__" + i + "[]']:checked"), function(){
                    format.push($(this).val());
                });
                var format_select = format.join(", ");
        
                if (format_select.includes("SEO") == true) {
                    var format_value_seo = 0.5;
                } else {
                    var format_value_seo = 0;
                };
                    
                if (format_select.includes("PR") == true) {
                    var format_value_pr = 1.5;
                } else {
                    var format_value_pr = 0;
                };
                    
                if (format_select.includes("Review") == true) {
                    var format_value_review = 2;
                } else {
                    var format_value_review = 0;
                };
                
                format_value[i] = format_value_seo + format_value_pr + format_value_review;
                
                
                // Set price
                    var format_basic = 12;

            };

                    var sum = format_value.reduce(function(a, b){
                        return a + b;
                    }, 0);
                    
                price = sum;

                $("input[name=price]").val(price);
                
                return false;
        
    });
```

Comment: `$("input[id='length']").length` should hopeful only return 1, since you should never have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: are you sure that's the full extent of the error? which line of that code throws the error?

Comment: your for loop `for (i = 1; i <= count_format; i++) {` ... starts at 1, and goes to length .... arrays start at index `0` to `length - 1` - that's your problem ... but ... since `value` is only ever set inside an onchange that's inside an onchange ... the value of `i` for ALL such occurrences will be `.length` ... and the code at the bottom is run before and `onchange` within `onchange` will ever run - not sure where your error is, but this code has no chance of producing the result you expect

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. You see, I 'm ok with .length and extracting sum of single loop.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I minimal it. Sorry about not clear to use this tool :)

Comment: I checked it. It 's broken in $("#format").on("change", function(){}. But why is it ok when I have not nested it?